# Finding region bounded by $z=1-x^2,\ z=x^2-1,\ y+z=1,$ and $y=0$ returns negative volume

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find region bounded by $z=1-x^2,\ z=x^2-1,\ y+z=1,$ and  $y=0$ This question seemed simple to me what I did was the following:

when plotting the x-z graph I find two parabolas creating a leaf-shaped image and $1-x^2 \leq z \leq x^2-1$ and I find that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ when plotting the y-z graph I find that $0 \leq y \leq 1-z$ thus I derive the following integral:

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{1-x^2}^{x^2-1}\int_0^{1-z}1dydzdx$$

when I evaluate this, I get a negative value!!

Is my analysis as to how to carry this problem out incorrect?

Comment: When $-1\le x\le1$ we have $x^2-1\le1-x^2$, not the other way around.

Comment: @GregMartin oh wait ur right